# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTypeId() on null

Tags: magento2

I am getting the below error while calling a function in my PHTML file

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTypeId() on null**

```
public function getCurrentProductDealDetail()
{
    $curPro = $this->coreRegistry->registry('current_product');
    $productType = $curPro->getTypeId();
    // echo $productType;
    // die("bdvf");
    $assDealDetails = [];
    if ($productType == "configurable") {
        $dataDeal = $this->getConfigAssociateProDeals(true);
    } elseif ($productType == "grouped") {
        $dataDeal = $this->getGroupAssociateProDeals(true);
    } else {
        $dataDeal = $this->helperData->getProductDealDetail($curPro);
        if ($dataDeal) {
            $dataDeal['entity_id'] = $curPro->getId();
        }
    }
    return $dataDeal;
}
```

**issue while calling the block here**

```
<div class="deal-timer">
<?php
                
blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('V\M\Block\ViewProduct');
$dealDetail = $blockObj->getCurrentProductDealDetail();
$product = $blockObj->getCurrentProduct();
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you tried to log the data of *$curPro*, are you getting the current product using registry?

Comment: yes am getting prod type there

Answer (score 0):

**Try getProductType()**

```
$curPro = $this->coreRegistry->registry('current_product');
$productType = $curPro->getProductType();
```

Comment: i was also getting value there with my code also

Comment: and yeah that too thworing the same error  for this getProductType()

Comment: try to print_r($curPro) and check you got product or not ??

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the product before getting the product type id?

```
$curPro = $this->coreRegistry->registry('current_product');
$productType = $curPro->getId();
```

If it works, then I think you can get the product type using your code.